# commit submodule using commit details from the parent in appveyor

Tags: git, powershell, git-submodules, appveyor

In an Appveyor build, I'm trying to commit a submodule using commit details from the parent repo as follows:

```
git commit -m $(git --git-dir=../.git log -1 --oneline)
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I've got a static site generator repository that builds static content into a GitHub pages submodule, when changes to the parent repo are PR'd into the master branch, the static content is automatically built and pushed to the GitHub pages submodule repo.

Anyway, this works in PowerShell (using posh-git) locally, however in Appveyor I get the following:

```
git commit -m $(git --git-dir=../.git log -1 --oneline)
error: unknown option `git-dir=../.git'
usage: git commit [<options>] [--] <pathspec>...
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use $ENV:APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_MESSAGE in your git commit message.

e.g.

```
git commit -m "'$ENV:APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_MESSAGE'"
```

This assumes your parent repo is the one that triggered the build.

Full list of appveyor environment variables at your disposal here: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/

Comment: Thank you Jim! Just note that in case you run command as CMD, use syntax like this: `git commit -m "%APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_MESSAGE%"`